# Voltage wave reflections in transmission line loaded by matched resistor

Tags: waves, voltage

Suppose I have a power source, a transmission line and a resistive load all connected together and all sharing the same impedance. If I send a voltage pulse starting at the power source, traveling through the transmission line and reaching the resistive load, I will have not voltage wave reflections because all the impedances match.

This is great but here is the thing. The load resistor does not really have the same impedance value in all places right? For example, If I have a 1-inch load resistor that is 200 ohms and divide the resistor in 4 pieces, each chuck would represent a resistance of 50 ohms. If I divide the resistor in 100 pieces, then each piece would represent 2 ohms. If I divide the resistor in 1,000,000 pieces, then each piece would represent 0.0002 ohms. I can continue to divide the resistor until the value of each piece is practically zero, which should mean that I should have a complete voltage wave reflection at the load because the voltage should see an open line (close to zero ohms).

In other words, my confusion stems from the idea that the impedance of a transmission line need to be identical at through the line at every point (to the infinitesimal level) but I don’t think this is the case of a resistor so why isn’t the wave bounding at the load?

Comment: Every post on this site is a question, so there's no need to indicate that the post is a question in the title. We have a [FAQ on writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: I may write a full answer later, but note that thinking of a resistor as a lumped element only works if the resistor is physically much smaller than the wavelength of the electrical signal applied to it. The transmission line, on the other hand, may be considerably longer. If the resistor were long compared to the wave length, then your intuition would be more correct.

Comment: @T555 - But your voltage pulse doesn't "see" all those little resistors that you divided the 200 ohm resistor into. The voltage pulse only "sees" the total resistance across the wires. And that total resistance is 200 ohms no matter how many itty-bitty pieces you cut it up into.

Comment: You can easily simulate with electrical simulation tools what it happening if your loads are not perfectly matched. Get yourself a copy of Spice (I prefer LTSpice) and you can numerically play with this as much as you like. In practice dividing lumped element approximations into more than about a dozen pieces won't buy you much, though. The main effects will already show up if you simulate your load cell as an LRC model.